# CANopen profile for multiple interfaces card

Tags: canopen

I want to build a microcontroller-based CAN node card that has interfaces like UART, SPI and I²C, to which connect different peripherals and interfaces, like say a EIA-485 counter or a SPI digital I/O expander. I'd like to define a profile for the card that's flexible enough to adapt to any possible configuration and include any device that can be connected to such node card. Since CANopen profiles seem to be pretty rigid, I researched CANopen virtual devices but that seems not the answer either.

Is there a standard for such functionality or I'm sailing unknown waters?

Answer (score 0):

You are sailing unknown waters unless you consider a CANopen bootloader a possible solution. There is no existing device profile that fits your criteria. CANopen is remarkably flexible but arbitrary extensibility is beyond it.

You could export the registers of your microcontroller 1:1 through the object dictionary and issue interrupts through PDOs. It would certainly be a fun exercise if just a bit impractical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand: how could a bootloader be the solution? To bootload a specific program for each configuration or peripheral added? I explored the posibility of making my node a gateway but couldn't find enough clear information about how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

From the [CAN in Automation](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=103) website:

> CANopen generic I/O modules are standardized in the [CiA 401](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=526) device
>   profile specification. The profile supports a granularity of 1-, 8-,
>   16-, and 32-bit for digital I/Os and a resolution of 1-, 2-, and
>   4-byte for analog I/Os.

However, it may be easier to implement a custom device, based on the general CiA 301 CANopen application layer and communication profile standard.  You could implement a set of general purpose [IOCTL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) functions using Manucturer objects (2000h to 5FFFh) and possibly use [SDO Block Transfer](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=152) to 'stream' data to specific OD objects representing connected device end points.

You will need to consider that, even with a bitrate of 1 Mbps at the physical layer, the CANopen protocol is never going to be able to keep up with a USB2 HS device when it comes to streaming data!  Also bear in mind that if you use PDOs for 'real-time' exchange of OD values there will be a significant lag and that the time quantum for PDO exchange is in the order of 25 ms or greater.

The final consideration is what CANopen master are you going to use?  If the product is to be commercially available then you will need to specify and document your EDS very carefully (maybe even providing an OPC or similar API).